How To Get The Amount of Records of a Report OnOpen Event in VBA Access 365
I need to get the amount of records of a Report (RecordCount) in the OnOpen event. if there's no record, I need to display a message to the user and close the report.
I tried to get this information thru the Report.Recordset, unsuccessfully. it says that it is available on ADP.
I'd appreciate your help.
thanks in advance.

Look into the OnNoData event.

@June7 this solution worked like a charm. on the Report_NoData(Cancel As Integer), I send a message informing that there's no data to print and right after I set Cancel = True. thanks a lot!
